# Convert BigQuery results to IEnumerable<MyClass>

Tags: c#, list, google-bigquery

Here is my code:

```
public  async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetQueryClass()
        {
            var elements = new List<MyClass>();
            var command = "my query is here";            
            var jobResults = await _client.ExecuteQueryAsync<MyClass>
                (command, parameters: null, new QueryOptions { UseLegacySql = true }, new { elements = elements.ToArray() }, cancellationToken: default);            
            return jobResults.AsList();
        }
```

Error message:

```
Error   CS0308  The non-generic method 'BigQueryClient.ExecuteQueryAsync(string, IEnumerable<MyClass>, QueryOptions, GetQueryResultsOptions, CancellationToken)' cannot be used with type arguments
```

MyClass is usual public class with `public string Name{ get; set; }`

Using is:

```
foreach(var z in await GetQueryClass())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(z.Name);
            }
```

What is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you are getting a compilation error. Can you cut and paste the message instead of paraphrasing? Also, can you indicate exactly which line of code has the error?

Comment: Done. Updated error message.

Comment: _client.ExecuteQueryAsync - this place has error mark

Comment: It says that `ExecuteQueryAsync` is not a generic method. You are supplying a type argument, with `ExecuteQueryAsync<MyClass>`. Can you explain?

Comment: I am trying to convert query results to the list, to use it after for my needs.

Comment: Usual key : value. Created class for it to store the results as class object